# How to change a form by select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to create a `<select>` tag above a from like this -

```
<select>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
</select>
```

when I select "student" show students form below. and when I select "teacher" then show teacher form below. How can I do this with bootstrap or jquery or javascript?

Comment: You've not really given enough information on your current code to help you, but http://api.jquery.com/change, http://api.jquery.com/val, http://api.jquery.com/hide and http://api.jquery.com/show should be enough to get you started

Comment: What you want is to listen to an event on your select control, __[This may help you](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)__

Comment: go to this link - https://onlineservices-servicesenligne.cic.gc.ca/eta/applicationQuery?lang=en&_ga=1.131923526.855304826.1485424171

and select "check your status". see 2nd input field is changed by select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```js
$('#choose-form').on('change', function(){
    $("#form-student, #form-teacher").hide('slow');
    var form = $(this).val();
    if(form == "student")
      $("#form-student").toggle('slow');
    if(form == "teacher")
      $("#form-teacher").toggle('slow');
  });
```

```css
#form-student, #form-teacher {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="choose-form">
  <option value="0">-</option>  
  <option value="student">Student</option>
  <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
</select>

<form id="form-student">
  <p>My student form</p>
</form>

<form id="form-teacher">
  <p>My teacher form</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   if(this.value == "Student") {
     // Show Student Form
     // hide teacher form
   } else if (this.value == "Teacher") {
     // Show Teacher Form
     // hide student form
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example of what you're trying to do. It should give you an idea of where to go.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content").hide();
    $('#my-select').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'Student')
      {
        $(".content").hide();
        $("#content-1").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == 'Teacher')
      {
        $(".content").hide();
        $("#content-2").show();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-select">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
</select>

<p class="content" id="content-1">I am a student.</p>

<p class="content" id="content-2">I am a teacher.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try this:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "Teacher") {
    $('input').remove();
    $("#myDiv").append("<input value='Teacher'/>");
  } else {
    $('input').remove();
    $("#myDiv").append("<input value='Student'/>");
  }  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
</select>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```